# What is "salpresado?"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, comida

I recently learned that "**salpresar**" can mean "**to salt,**" but when I tried to find real world examples of its usage online, I kept running into entries that appeared to be referring to it as some sort of specific dish.  I attempted to see if the Spanish Wikipedia might have more to say about this, but did not find anything substantive.

**If "salpresado" is primarily used to refer to a specific dish, can anyone tell me a little more about it?**  Photos would also be helpful.  I did see some that may be associated with "salpresado," but they all looked so different that I was unable to identify any distinguishing characteristics.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo You should convert your comment in an answer.

Comment: "To salt" is "salar". I had never heard of "salpresado", but I'm not a "cocinitas" either.

Comment: @DGaleano done!

Comment: It seems to be an old word. If you search in ngrams, most uses are from 19th century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pictures you looked at were so different because *salpresar* does not refer to any specific dish, but to a cooking technique. According to the [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X5ZEuu2), it means "to salt something and then press it so it can be preserved". I suppose the pictures just show the food being processed with this technique.

Comment: Muy informativo!  Gracias!!